# CSS issue with removing margin around main slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The main header fluid menu background stays in Firefox and Safari only, when I added the following,

```
#feature .post{
position:absolute;
z-index:99999;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Just noticed in the net console that many of the css and js files that you're including are either not there (404) or have the wrong permissions (403). Also you include 2 different jquery versions which should be avoided, though only one of them - 1.11.0 -  is currently found and loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For 3rd Issue, you have not mentioned the style for mobile device width eg. min 320px.
You can do it as -

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {

 .container 
 {
         width: 320px;
         margin:0;
 }
.title
 {
         margin:0;
 }
 h2
 {
         font-size:14px;
 }

}
```

Change the margin and font size accordingly.